# How to drop 2 or more columns based on column name, type and statistics such as std in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to drop all the columns containing k1 and p5 and have a new DataFrame without those columns but I get an error.

```
df_r1 =  df.filter(regex=("k1\s")) #filter all k1 columns
df_r2 =  df.filter(regex=("p5\s")) #filter all p5 columns

df_dropped_new = df.drop((df_r1,df_r2),axis = 1)
```

and the above line gets me the following error

```
DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Furthermore, I am performing 2 more filters to my dataFrame. The first one is dropping columns containing "objects" and the second one is dropping columns that have std=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'p5 sd':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'k1 s':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'V':[5,5,5,5,5,5],
                   'k1 d':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  C  V k1 d  k1 s  p5 sd
0  a  7  5    a     1      4
1  b  8  5    a     3      5
2  c  9  5    a     5      4
3  d  4  5    b     7      5
4  e  2  5    b     1      5
5  f  3  5    b     0      4
```

First check if `std` is `0`, but it remove all not numeric columns, so add them by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with `fill_value=True`:

```
m1 = df.std().eq(0).reindex(df.columns, fill_value=True)
```

Then check if contains columns names pattern:

```
m2 = m1.index.str.contains("p5\s|k1\s")

print (m1)
A         True
C        False
V         True
k1 d      True
k1 s     False
p5 sd    False
dtype: bool

print (m2)
[False False False  True  True  True]
```

Chain both masks together by `or` (`|`):

```
m = m1 | m2
print (m)
A         True
C        False
V         True
k1 d      True
k1 s      True
p5 sd     True
dtype: bool
```

Last filter, but is necessary invert mask by `~`:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~m]
print (df)
   C
0  7
1  8
2  9
3  4
4  2
5  3
```

EDIT:

`Mask` for remove not numeric columns is not necessary, because `std` automatically removing non numeric columns:

```
m0 = df.columns.isin(df.select_dtypes(include=['object']))
m1 = df.std().eq(0).reindex(df.columns, fill_value=True)
m2 = m1.index.str.contains("p5\s|k1\s")
m = m1 | m2 | m0
print (m)
A         True
C        False
V         True
k1 d      True
k1 s      True
p5 sd     True
dtype: bool

df = df.loc[:, ~m]
print (df)
   C
0  7
1  8
2  9
3  4
4  2
5  3
```

Comment: this doesn't directly work for me because I am performing two more filters, the first filter is dropping all columns containing 'object' and the second filter is dropping all columns that have 'std = 0'. Thats beside containing the following strings. Sorry for not clarifying that earlier. Thats why in the question, I insisted on that specific method.

Comment: @MajidHelmy - No problem, give some time.

Comment: @MajidHelmy - I add solution for all filters

Comment: @jezrael, this looks promising and to drop the column types, do I simply add a third mask such as 
m3=m2.select_dtypes(include=['object']) 
and then I drop all of them, 
m = m3|m2|m1 and then df=df.loc[; ~m]

Comment: @MajidHelmy - yes exactly.

Comment: @ayhan your solution is also great ! you must keep it, so people have diversity.

Comment: @ayhan - removed, so sorry.

Comment: @ayhan just re-post it, I think its also great !

Comment: @jezrael , I will re-edit the question now to fit all of this in your code. However when I use "m3 = m2.select_dtypes(include=['object']) ", I get "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'select_dtypes'"

Comment: Hmm, I think you dont need this condition, because `std` removed all object columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163793/discussion-between-majid-helmy-and-jezrael).